# Margin inconsistencies

Tags: geometry

So in my document I defined the left margin as 3cm and right as 2.5. would there be any reason for the margin to come out as nearly 3.5 and 3 when measuring the printed document?

```
%Document Declerations
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}

%margin Settings
\usepackage[inner=3cm, outer=2.54cm, top=2.54cm, bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: Exactly how did you print? Many pdf viewers will by default actually scale the contents.

Comment: I printed from Adobe reader, thanks

Comment: There could be a gutter added to the page, which adds to the margins. Or, possibly, the print margin could have scaled (shrunk) the output to fit.

Comment: did you specify the same page size (a4paper or letterpaper) as your physical paper?

Comment: Although I think this shouldn't have an effect when you specify margin dimensions, are you specifying `twoside` ore using a document class that is by default two-sided?

Comment: How exactly did you specify the margins? Did you specify any other dimensions for the page layout?

Comment: Hi all, I've attached the code

Comment: Why do youy mention 2.5cm when you are using 2.54cm (approx 1in)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware that was a mistake on my side. Still doesn't explain the discrepancy